# parse string to date with given information

Tags: parsing, grails, groovy

I knew that there some issues like this in this page but I didn't find my answer, please help me solve this.
I got:

```
params.month = JANUARY
params.year = 2014
params.date = 10
```

I tried

```
def parse = new Date(2014, JANUARY, 10)
print parse(format(yyyy/MM/dd))
```

result:

```
2014/01/10
```

but When i tried

```
def parse = new Date(params.year.toInteger(), params.month.toInteger(), params.date.toInteger())
```

it can't parse `params.month.toInteger()`

Comment: JANUARY means month JANUARY (01)

Comment: instead of 01 change it to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use deprecated constructors such as [`Date(year, month, day)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

I recommend to use the Groovy JDK method [`parse`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in order to create a Date instance.

```
def yourDateInstance = Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd, "${params.year}/${params.month}/${params.date}")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def parse = new Date(2014, 0 , 10)
```

NOTE: In java Months start with 0 ,0=JANUARY

And Date constructor has signature **Date(int year,int month,int date)** ,this is the cause of the exception as JANUARY is a string so it can't be parsed to int

Comment: That constructor has been deprecated since Java 1.1 (1997!)